# Iniciar sesión con el ID

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Como podría iniciar sesión con el id que me genera el xmlrpc, sin necesidad de poner usuario y contraseña?

Método donde aprueba la conexión y me da un id, si me coincide con el id al hacer callAsync que me lleve a otra mainactivity.

```
 try {
                    listener = new XMLRPCCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(long id, Object result) {
                            if(iConexion==id) {
                                code = String.valueOf(result);
                                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                                if (vibrator != null) {
                                    vibrator.vibrate(100);
                                }
                                Intent WindowCode = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WindowCode.class);
                                WindowCode.putExtra(Constantes.CODE, code);
                                startActivity(WindowCode);
                            }else{
                                Log.e("ID","Se han producido varios errores");
                            }
                        }
```

Esta es la llamada asincrona.

```
iConexion = client.callAsync(listener, Constantes.SERVER_PHP, new Object[]{user, passw});
```

Comment: Lo que puedo hacer es decirle que un String id = String.valueOf(iConexion), pero no sé si esto está bien realizado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución sería esta:

```
iConexion = client.callAsync(listener, Constantes.SERVER_PHP, new Object[]{id = String.valueOf(iConexion), Constants.TOKEN});
```

Creamos un objeto de tipo String llamado id y le pasamos el valor id que genera la llamada automáticamente para la identificación.